# Scroll to div position unless browser back button is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using hash in url (like http://somepage.com/text#hash) scrolling to div with id #hash. This works fine. But when user click on the back button I don't want to scroll to #hash position but to position the user left. I'm thinking about storing the position in localStorage but how can I determine if the back button was pressed?

Answer (score 0):

You can detect when the Hash of your URL Changes, like this:

```
window.onhashchange = function () {
  if (window.innerDocClick) {
    //Your own in-page mechanism triggered the hash change
  } else {
    //Browser back or forward button was pressed
  }
};
```